# Hosting more than one site in a wamp server

Tags: hosting

I have two different sites and i want to host both of them through wamp server for example, my first site is http://one.gov.ae and the second one is http://two.gov.ae

what I want is when I type the first site it should open the index for the first one and i when i type the second one it should open the second site.

but whatever I type it open the index for the first one

however I add both sits in httpd-vhosts.con and uncomment  the following line in http.conf

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

So anyone can tell me what I can do in such situation

here is my httpd-vhosts.conf code

```
<VirtualHost 172.20.10.121:80>
   # ServerAdmin admin@localhost
     DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www"
     ServerName localhost
   # ServerAlias www.dummy-host.localhost
   # ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.localhost-error.log"
   # CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.localhost-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 172.20.10.121:8080>
   # ServerAdmin webmaster@meera.am.gov.ae
     ServerName meera.am.gov.ae
     DocumentRoot "c:wamp/www/meera"
     Directoryindex index.php index.html
   # ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.localhost-error.log"
   # CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.localhost-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

I comment the following in httpd file

```
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being 
# viewed by Web clients. 
#
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
  #  Order allow,deny
  #  Deny from all
  # Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Can you post your httpf-vohosts.conf?

Comment: `prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being 
viewed by Web clients` **DO NOT COMMENT OUT** these lines. As the documentation says it stops these files form **being sent to the clients** does not stop them form working. (And overriding default options).

Answer (score 1):

> but whatever I type it open the index for the first one

So I guess your server does listen on the port 8080 too. You did not mention that part.

The problem could be that you also enabbled name based virtual hosting with something like:

```
NameVirtualHost *
```

... or

```
NameVirtualHost 172.20.10.121
```

This way Apache is identifying hosts by hostname (the `Host` request header). If no host is sent or no matching `ServerName` found in config, the first host (the default host) will handle the request.

Although instead of this port madness I strongly recommend you using name-based virtual hosts. With names like `mysite.test` or `jopbsite.test` or `projectname.test` etc. This way they can all listen on port 80, you have to define the `ServerName` for all of the hosts, enbale name based virtual hosting with one of my examples above then define your NS entries in:

```
c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

file.

**Edit:**

ou should have something like this in your vhosts.conf:

```
NameVirtualHost *

<VirtualHost *>
     ServerName mysite.test

     DocumentRoot "C:/www/mysite.test"
     Directoryindex index.php index.html
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
     ServerName theothersite.test

     DocumentRoot "C:/www/theothersite.test"
     Directoryindex index.php index.html
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: dear where i should make the above changes i mean in which file

Comment: i made the changed as you said in httpd-vhosts.cong but still is not working for me

Comment: @Meera I added an example to my answer withthe essentials.

Comment: @vbence i did this too but still not working only one website is working the other one it giving me error like you have to login

Comment: @Meera Do you open them as `http://mysite.test` and `http://theothersite.test` in the browser? If you have any .htaccess files try to disable them for no.

Comment: @vbence yes i open them like http://mysite.test how i can disable htaccess files?

Comment: @Meera You can rename them for example.

Comment: @vbence where i can find these files

Comment: @Meera They are inside the document root and modify Apache settings for the folder they reside in. Typically this is the way password protection is set up fr individual directories. - But for the sake f the test, it's best to have only an `index.html` in the two DosucmentRoot folders. - also: do not use interecting directories for your sites.

Comment: @vbence i rename the htaccess files but still it giving me this message 

"This website requires you to log in"

Comment: @Meera It looks like you have a `<directory>` somewhere in your config file**s**. Search for the `Require` directive and you will find where the config asks for a password.

Comment: @vbence i made some changes in httpd file see update in my question

Comment: @vbence now i am getting the error message for index page and rest of pages are working fine

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of detailed tutorials on this. I haven't used WAMP in a while but this is the guide I used when I did last: http://cesaric.com/?p=255

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem a while back and I found out that it was a silly mistake that I didn't do a restart on the httpd server.

You could try running this from a command prompt if you have the `/bin` directory linked in your `PATH`:

```
httpd -k restart
```

Hope it helps ! Cheers :)

Comment: @Meera httpd.exe should be in the \bin directory. For instance, if you used the default for a Windows Apache setup it'll be in <install directory>\Apache2.2\bin. This should be in your user PATH found under 'Environment Variables' in windows. You just need to append that directory where your httpd.exe is found to the PATH variable and you should be able to run 'httpd.exe' directly from Command Prompt. In the alternative, you may just go directly to your Apache directory where your httpd.exe is found and run the command: httpd -k restart

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to modify your .conf to account for two separate virtual hosts.

In the below example you'll basically need to set the ServerName, ServerAlias and other variables in order to separate them.

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.org
    ServerName  www.example.org
    ServerAlias example.org

    # Indexes + Directory Root.
    DirectoryIndex index.html
    DocumentRoot /home/www/www.example.org/htdocs/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    ServerName  www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com

    # Indexes + Directory Root.
    DirectoryIndex index.html
    DocumentRoot /home/www/www.example.com/htdocs/
</VirtualHost>
```

Hope that helps. Be sure to stop Apache before modifying the .conf file and then start it again.

Comment: i already create two separate virtual host but still not working for me